# Keeping variables and methods private when using classes via protocols in swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, protocols, private

Today I came to a question, what is the point of keeping class fields/variables and methods private, if you are using those class instances as protocol instances. For instance,

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
  func someProtocolMethod()
} 

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
  private var someVariable = ""
  func someProtocolMethod() { }
}

class SuperClass {
  var someInstance: SomeProtocol?

  func superMethod() {
    someInstance.someProtocolMethod()
  }
}

let superInstance = SuperClass()
let someInstance = SomeClass()
superInstance.someInstance = someInstance
```

Here in `SomeClass` we have private variable called `someVariable`. Usually, I write it down as a private variable intuitively for the sake of SOLID encapsulation type-of-thing. As I was writing tests today, I came up to a question, isn't it already encapsulated and safe with only pointing to protocol? Does it have any disadvantages, if I don't use direct class instances and keep variables and methods public?

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not facing any problem in accessing the variable from superclass. May be I haven't asked the question right, but this is just a question about is there any disadvantages of keeping variables/methods of concrete class public, if we are working with those classes only via protocol pointers.

Comment: But you can't be sure you are always working with protocol types so for that reason it might be needed to use private if no other class in the same module/library should be able to change it

Comment: @JoakimDanielson lets consider that we are always working with protocol types, so is there any other disadvantages? Maybe any performance issues?

Comment: My whole point is that you can not consider that nor should you rely on it, so if it is important that a property or function is private for any reason then make them private.

Comment: Ok, I misread your question. I agree with Joakim, whether a property should be private or not is nothing to do with what protocols an object conforms to. Even if you say you are only accessing via protocols, you can't guarantee that. There are no performance issues at runtime since access is checked at compile time.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing known from the outside world about `someInstance` is that it complies with protocol `SomeProtocol`.  So there seem to be no risk of the outside world that accesses  `someInstance` could access `someVariable` if it were public.

However, this is not sufficient to justify making the variable public.  I can see at least 3 reasons not to do so:

- `SomeClass` can be used on its own, and not only via the protocols it complies with. After all, reuse is one of the driver in OO design.  In this case, making public something that should be private for could later reveal to be short-sighted.
- The context that initialises `someInstance` knows very well the real type of the object and could misuse public properties that are not meant to be changed directly. Here the risk is in the last 3 lines of your example.
- Finally, some [downcasting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID341) could be done to the real type, which would then expose public members that should be private:

  ```
    class SuperClass {
      var someInstance: SomeProtocol?   // optional or initializer

      func superMethod() {
          someInstance?.someProtocolMethod()
          if let oops = someInstance as? SomeClass {  // Downcast
              oops.someVariable = "hacked!"           // successful
              print (oops.someVariable)
          }
          else {
              print ("No access")                     // downcast failed
          }

      }
    }
  ```

Conclusion: **Always keep private what doesn't have to be public**. Of course, if all these classes are of limited use, i.e. only for testing purpose and if you're the only maintainer, the risk of misuse can be low.  But why taking bad habits; think of your legacy ;-)

Regarding performance, there is no difference here between the public and private access. [Access](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html) is managed at compile/assembly time.
The performance here is slightly impacted by the protocol which implies [dynamic dispatch](https://towardsdev.com/method-dispatch-in-swift-protocols-7b1323338468). But unless you write an operating system or a a function called in the main loop of a video-game it is so small that it's not relevant.